# How can one suppress automatic refresh of open browser windows on the iPhone, iPad, etc. when switching back into them?

Tags: iphone, ipad, browser, suppress

The question is: How can one suppress the annoying auto-refresh of open web browsers in Safari, etc., when the user of an iPhone or iPad switches back into it after switching out of it?  There appears to be no setting that can do this on these devices.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on http://apple.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

Today I inadvertently discovered a way to stop this annoying behavior, even though it does not qualify as a real fix, it is a method of suppressing the behavior by taking a simple action every time prior to switching out from Safari or another browser.  Not ideal, but it does give you control (finally) of the browser such that the behavior is suppressed.  The link to the answer is here:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/25254749#25254749

If you don't feel like surfing there, here's the trick:

In Safari or another browser app, touch and hold on a piece of text (a single word or letter is fine), then lift your finger off the screen.  The word or letter will be selected and the familiar little pop-up that says "Copy | Define" appears.  Touch "Define" and the screen that shows the word's definition or says it couldn't find a definition pops up.  Now, do *not* touch anything else; not "Done", "Search the Web", or anything else. Now press the Home button (i.e., the one on the bottom portion of the front face panel of the iPhone with the square in it).  You will be switched back to the springboard with all your app icons and from there can do anything else you want.  Then, touch the browser icon for the browser you were in and you'll switch back into it.  The definition screen covering the browser window will still be there.  Touch "Done", and the screen drops away.  Blessedly, the open browser window(s) will *not* reload.

**Update:**

In Mercury, the trick hasn't failed me so far.  However in Safari, sometimes it fails to work when many apps are backgrounded and many browser windows are open.  Possibly because Safari is bundled with iOS and written by devs in the same company, the Springboard may have more hooks into it and been programmed to have more discretionary power over its behavior.  And a blocking process initiated by Springboard is cancellable by Springboard; if not, then it'd hardly be consistently useful as an OS.  But I have noticed that by placing Safari in its select-browser state (touch the lower-right one-square-on-top-of-the-other icon in Safari that causes the browser windows to stack tilting forward, pseudo-3D style) and then switching out to the Springboard and doing whatever, etc., then back into Safari, that also seems to work, even with a lot of browser windows and apps open.  But as we all know, some web pages have Javascript that force an auto-refresh based on last date-time of retrieval which they store in their DOM, usually in a hidden field or some other place.  So that can't be helped when a browser window becomes active.  However lacking that, the window doesn't refresh.  So in terms of getting consistently positive results when trying to suppress auto-reload when using Safari, I recommend this approach more often than the more general one I described first.

Comment: Still relevant in 2023, life saver, can replicate a `firebase | realtime DB` loading issue in `Safari` - that occurs specially when this `inactive` state occurs.